# Trouble with jQuery Plugin -Quicksand

Tags: jquery, wordpress, quicksand

I love this plugin and I'm trying to implement it into a custom photo gallery for a clients new web-site. Trouble is troubleshooting. I have a working version of this on my own site and the output html is accurate. I've verified. So I don't know if this is a WP problem or if I'm not including another dependent plugin. Think jQuery and Easing are enough...
Heres a sample of the code;

```
    <!--  Begin portfolio box -->
    <div class="galleryNudge"  style="margin-left:-90px;">
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $post_per_page = 20; // -1 shows all posts
    $do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
    $args=array(
    'post_type' => array ('post'),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
    );
    $pf_categorynotin = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, true);
    if($pf_categorynotin){
    $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $pf_categorynotin,
    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
    )
    ); //category__in
    }
    $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
    if( have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<ul id="applications" class="image-grid pf_item3" style="width:700px;">';
    $r = 0;
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    $post_cat = array();
    //$post_cat = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
    $post_cat = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, "category");
    $post_cats = array();
    $post_rel = "";
    for($h=0;$h<count($post_cat);$h++){
    $post_rel .= $post_cat[$h]->slug.' ';
    $post_cats[] = $post_cat[$h]->name;
    }
    $r++;
    echo'<li data-id="id-'. $r .'" data-type="'.$post_rel.'" style="display:inline;">';
    if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'port_thumb_image_url', true)) { ?>
    <a  class="tozoom" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'port_large_image_url', true); ?>" rel="example4" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'port_thumb_image_url', true); ?>" class="portfolio_box" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="199px" height="134px" /><span class="gallery-mag-glass3"></span></a>
    <?php } ?>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and it's generating the html correctly. I've gotten rid of unnecessary categories and cleaned up the output as best I can.
The working demo can be found here: http://favaldesign.com/blog/portfolio/

And the inoperable page is here: http://marbledesigns.net/marbledesigns/?page_id=9

My custom Quicksand script is here: http://www.marbledesigns.net/marbledesigns/wp-content/themes/blaxk/js/QuickSand/jquery.quicksand.flow.js

If it helps firebug has shown no errors. Many thanks to anyone willing to look this over and lend me a hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... problem was a simple (yet embarrassing) jQuery conflict. Changed lines 24-25 to

`var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Now that that is fixed I can get back to more important things. Like making it sort within the container.

If this question is useless, please delete.